# Grails cascade delete?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm going nuts with foreign key constraints here. No matter what I specify for cascading behavior or `belongsTo/hasMany`, I get a foreign-key constraint error

I have this:

```
class A{
}

class B{
}

class C extends B {
   static belongsTo = [a: A]
}
```

I want to run `A.list()*.delete()`

What do I need to do to get `C` to cascade delete with `A`?

Comment: Could you post the foreign-key constraint error?

Comment: Could not execute update query: SQL [ delete form A where deleted=?] constraint [fk<hash]; nested exception is ...ConstraintViolationException: could not execute update query.

Comment: My actual delete is an `executeUpdate` with `delete from A where condition`, as I'm deleting many records and can't afford to iterate delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added mappings in `class A` ?

```
class A{

    static hasMany=[c:C]
    static mappedBy=[c:"cColumn"]
}
```

As I understand from [this](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html), both mappings should be present

Comment: In the latest version of the docs (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.3.3%20Understanding%20Cascading%20Updates%20and%20Deletes) it shows a relationship with this mapping as 'unidirectional one-to-one' so I think you may be on to something here.

Comment: This fails, because only C defines the column. If I move the field up to the base class B, I still get this error, whether I use executeUpdate or *.delete();

Comment: It looks like you need this AND

`A.withNewSession{
  A.findByBlah()*.delete()
}` This seems a little crazy, but it's the only thing that can pass my foreign key integration test, and I don't know why.

Comment: The answer is wrong. According to your question, `A` does not has many `B`'s, but C's. Additionally you do not need `mappedBy`. If you do it like that, it will definitely cascade.

Comment: My integration tests to test foreign key constraint deletion cascading fail without `mappedBy`, so it seems pretty necessary. I don't care what the documentation says.